# How to change delegate’s sizeHint on TableView’s cell focus?

Tags: qt, delegates, model-view, sizehint

I've got some troubles with custom delegate's *sizeHint*:
I want to "unfold" cell (row with this cell) on it's focus; otherwise return default size;
QTableVew connected to resize rows on mouse press:

```
connect(m_scheduleView, &QTableView::pressed, m_scheduleView, &QTableView::resizeRowsToContents);

QSize DBScheduleItemDelegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (option.state & QStyle::State_HasFocus) {
        ... // this block never executes;
        return // some calculated size;
    }
return QSize(width, height); // default size; 
}
```

Code in conditional block has never executed, but the same condition on delegate's *paint()* executes properly:

```
void DBScheduleItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (option.state & QStyle::State_HasFocus)
        painter->fillRect(...);
}
```

So, how to catch cell focus in *sizeHint*?

Comment: Does `if (option.state & QStyle::State_Selected)` help?

Comment: @Nejat , I've tried, didn't help

Answer (score 0):

This is related to https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-5392 .

A possible work-around that is also used in the source code of Qt Creator itself (specifically in the `TaskView` widget) is to keep track of the current/selected item(s) yourself by connecting to the `QItemSelectionModel`.